# PHP Warning: ibase_query(): supplied resource is not a valid Firebird/InterBase link resource

Tags: php, iis, firebird

When I submit the form of register new user or new client, this message error appears.

I'm using PHP 7.1.5 with IIS Server in a Windows 10 OS. The same code was working correctly and stop work from nothing.

Somebody can help me?

Here is the code:

```
enter code here
<?php 

if (!isset($_SESSION))  {
  session_start();
 }

// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
  // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
  // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location: login.php"); exit;
 }

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nome = $_POST['txt_nome'];
    $email = $_POST['txt_email'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['txt_cpassword'];
    $nivel = $_POST['txt_nivel'];
    $pass=strcmp($password,$cpassword);

  if($pass == 0){
    $senha = md5($password);
    }else{
    echo 'As Senhas Não Conferem. Verifique!';
 }

 if ($nivel == '1 - Diretoria') {
    $nivel = 1;
 }else if ($nivel == '2 - Gerência'){
    $nivel = 2;
 }else if ($nivel == '3 - Usuários'){
    $nivel = 3;
 }

    $cad_usur = "INSERT INTO C_USUR 
  (C_USUR_USUR,C_USUR_STUS,C_USUR_NOME,C_USUR_LGIN,C_USUR_PSWD,C_USUR_NIVL)
                     VALUES ((SELECT S_CONT_CONT FROM 
 SP_PROX_NRMO('0001','C_USUR')),'1','$nome','$email','$senha','$nivel')";

    $insert_usur = ibase_query($cad_usur);

 if($cad_usur == true){
    echo 'Cadastro Realizado Com Sucesso';
 }else{
    echo 'Não foi possível cadastrar o usuário. Verifique!';
 }

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Two mistakes: 1) ibase_query should have the first parameter - database connection, and only second parameter is the query - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-query.php 2) you should COMMIT the transaction after calling query, or the data most probably would not be inserted.

Comment: One more mistake, splicing user input into SQL command you open your database for every script kiddie to crack it open. Do not ever put user-input variables into the SQL query. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Arioch'The The documentation you link shows that the first parameter is optional, otherwise the last opened connection is assumed.

Comment: Please show where you open the connection, and otherwise follow the first comment by Arioch'The that you need to open a connection and pass it to `ibase_query`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel experienced people may cut corners: they know preconditions and if they screw they know how to investigate it and turn their failure into a lesson. Novices should do by the book instead. HTTP server is multi-threading or even mutil-processing. How connections created in one php process accessed from another ? What about parallel connections ? Everything you did not passed explicitly is a guesswork about race conditions

Comment: I'm calling my connection just in the login page. I need to call the connection in every page where I will use an database integration?

Comment: Answer to that question is hidden in implementation details of PHP, IIS and PHP to IIS bridge. On the theoretical side, HTTP pages are all separate, see REST API. Every HTTP request in theory has no any shared information/context with any other request. To which extent this rule can be violated and globally-shared variable created in PHP-for-IIS I do not know